# Android: Dynamically populating GridLayout

Tags: java, android, android-gridlayout

I'm trying to create an activity where I have a GridLayout that is populated dynamically:

Here's the xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="GoalsActivity" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/goals_grid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center" >
        </GridLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here's the activity:

```
public class GoalsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_goals);
        try {
            JSONArray goals = new JSONArray(getIntent().getStringExtra("GOAL_LIST"));
            GridLayout goalsGrid = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.goals_grid);

            for(int i = 0; i <= goals.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject goal = goals.getJSONObject(i);
                TextView goalView = new TextView(GoalsActivity.this);
                goalView.setHeight(125);
                goalView.setWidth(125);
                goalView.setText(goal.getString("name"));
                goalsGrid.addView(goalView);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to display the goals using a GridLayout but whenever I run this code, the following happens:

[image: GirdLayout problem]

Apparently all TextViews are stacking on top of each other, but if I add 2 of these:

```
<TextView
    android:height="125dp"
    android:width="125dp" />
```

under the GridLayout in my xml layout manually, they show up just like I need them to:

[image: Grid size]

[image: TextView size]

I can't figure out how to fix this, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Well, just give an advice. You can use RecyclerView to make a list like that. It's more powerfull and easier man

Comment: For your problem, try to set the width of the grid layout to `match_parent`

Comment: If I set the width of the grid layout to `match_parent`, the TextViews will still overlap and just float to the left side of the screen.